# How to load enviroment variable script inside singularity container in snakemake

Tags: python, snakemake, singularity-container

Consider the following `snakemake` rule:

```
rule all:
    singularity: "./ubuntu.sif"
    output: "tmp.txt"
    shell: """
    python --version >> tmp.txt
    """
```

when I run it as `snakemake -c1 --use-singularity` it gives an error because the python interpreter in not in PATH in the container.

```
Activating singularity image ./ubuntu.sif
/usr/bin/bash: line 2: python: command not found
[Sun Jul 10 17:49:04 2022]
Error in rule all:
    jobid: 0
```

How can I make snakemake run a "source /some/path/to/env.sh" command on the singularity container?

---

I know I can run the rule as

```
rule all:
    output: "tmp.txt"
    shell: """
    singularity exec ./ubuntu.sif /path/to/python --version >> tmp.txt
    """
```

But it seems much more hacky solution than providing simple "singularity" parameter. And that is how people are using it currently. I do not have root access so i cannot modify the container's `.singularity.d` content.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to side load a special environment, it might be better to ask: why is it *not* in `PATH`?

---

Answer 1: you're calling `python` as opposed to `python3`

Ubuntu uses explicitly versioned `python2` / `python3` binaries, unless symlinks were created either manually or via the `python[23]-is-python` package. Try using `python3 --version` rather than `python --version`.

---

Answer 2: your local `PATH` variable is overriding the container environment

I'm not sure how snakemake handles this, but by default singularity makes the full environment it was executed in available inside the container. This makes running a singularity image more like running a shell script rather than a completely separate environment as one gets when running Docker containers.

You can use the `--cleanenv`/`-e` flag when calling singularity to ensure that only `SINGULARITYENV_*` variables are forwarded to the container environment.

Comment: Sorry I did not fully understand. Dies singularity maintains a snapshot of env vars which were present when it was created? Otherwise how would the container get correct PATH? I tried adding the location to `/path/to/python` in my shell env PATH. But singularity still does not get correct path. My current workaround looks like `singularity exec ../ubuntu_torch_noenv.sif /bin/bash -c "source /filesystem/bashrc;conda activate trial;python --version"`, i.e give load bashrc command in snakemake shell directly.

Comment: Something like `PATH=/filesystem/anaconda/envs/trial/bin/python /usr/bin/singularity  exec ../ubuntu_torch_noenv.sif /bin/bash -c "python --version"` does not work. So I am not sure how shell env passes to singularity. `-e` showed results no different.

Comment: again, the most likely solution is to use `python3` and not `python`

Comment: No. I get the same error. Issue is that python is not at a standard PATH.

Comment: It sounds like snakemake is isolating the container environment. The simplest solution might be to just write a wrapper script in the current directory with whatever environment modifications and have singularity run that rather than the `python ...` directly. Or to build a different image that is set up in a more helpful manner.